# Function tha returns values by pairs with somme eventually nil one

Tags: lua

I try to make a function that calculate intersection points between to circles: one circle against a list of circles.

For each case there are 0,1 or 2 intersection points.

I want the function returns nil, nil for 0 points, z0, nil for 1 and z1, z2 for 2 points. I thought collecting gradually the pairs of results in a table through a loop, and unpack it at the end, but a table doesn't take a nil value.

I tried this for the moment. How can I achieve what I want ?

```
function InterSection_Cercles (Ca , ... )

    local C = table.pack( ... )
    local d, CosTheta, Theta, i
    local t = {}

    for i = 1, C.n do

        d = complex.abs ( Ca.Ct - C[i].Ct )

        CosTheta = round (((Ca.Ry * Ca.Ry + d * d - C[i].Ry * C[i].Ry) /( 2 * Ca.Ry * d )) , 10 )

        Theta = round ( math.acos( CosTheta ) , Prec)

        if not Theta then -- 0 solution
            -- table.insert( t , nil ) useless
            -- table.insert( t , nil )
        elseif Theta == 0 then -- 1 solution 
            table.insert( t , Ca.Ct + complex.polar (Ca.Ry , Theta + complex.arg (C[i].Ct -Ca.Ct)))
            -- table.insert( t , nil ) useless
        else -- 2 solitions
            table.insert( t , Ca.Ct + complex.polar (Ca.Ry , Theta + complex.arg (C[i].Ct -Ca.Ct)))
            table.insert( t , Ca.Ct + complex.polar (Ca.Ry , -Theta + complex.arg (C[i].Ct -Ca.Ct)))
        end -- if

    end -- for

    return table.unpack ( t )

end -- function
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to build an array in Lua that contains `nil` values. Arrays in Lua are defined as the sequence in a table from [1, n] which has no `nil` values in it.

You could either insert a placeholder value (`false`) or you will have to keep track of the table's size manually. So rather than calling `table.insert`, you have to make a new function that stores the length of the table in some value:

```
local function manualInsert(tbl, val)
  if(not tbl.n) then tbl.n = 0 end --all values are assumed to be inserted through this function.
  tbl[tbl.n + 1] = val
  tbl.n = tbl.n + 1
end
```

Normally, `tbl` cannot be used with standard Lua mechanisms for dealing with arrays. You can't call `#` on it to get the right length, so iterating over it is difficult *unless* you know it's special. Removing elements would need its own special function, and so forth.

However, you can use a metatable and metamethods to make using this kind of pseudo-array seem more functional. For example, in Lua 5.2+, you can override the `__len` metamethod to return `n`. This would allow you use `for i = 1, #tbl do` to iterate over the elements. It would also allow `table.unpack` to work without manually passing the length, since it's defined to use `#` to get the length if you don't provide it.

Note that while Lua 5.1 does allow the use of the `__len` metamethod, it does not permit a *table* to override the default length computation. Only userdata's `__len` metamethods are used.

In Lua 5.2, you can override the `__ipairs` metamethod in order to make `ipairs` work. In Lua 5.3, this is deprecated; `ipairs` relies on the standard metamethods instead. This could be workable, but the documentation says that `ipairs` will keep going "up to the first nil value." So it may not be possible in Lua 5.3.

So unless you're in Lua 5.2 or better, `manualInsert` will create a very dysfunctional table.

Comment: The number of elements expected is twice the number of circles in ... two per circle. That means that tey are more than two. It is a list of pair of points, some of them may be nil. If one is missing then will append a shift and a misinterpretation of the results. A point will be use for a wrong circle. The solution I try to avoid for typesetting reason is to return a table per circle. An empty table mean all nil. A table of one element has is second nil and a full table of two elements is OK. I want to avoid the use of many

Comment: Thanks ! `false` is the right approach, I didn't think about it !

Answer (score 2):

If using *nil* inside tables is complicating life for your, use some other value like *false*.

Or return a table like `{ 0, 1, z1, 2, z1, z2 }`.

Comment: I prefer avoid the use of a third value to test.